# Magento: addEventListener on change radio button not working using requirejs

Tags: magento2, module, javascript, requirejs

Here everything works fine just one issue is there, it doesn't the value and id of input radio fields, So I think domReady addEventListener is not working here.

Help is really appreciated
TIA

This is phtml file code

```
<?php
$productId  = $block->getCurrentProduct()->getId();
$productPriceDecimal  = $block->getCurrentProduct()->getPrice();
$productPrice = number_format((float)$productPriceDecimal, 2, '.', '');
$attributeData = $block->getCurrentProduct()->getData('allow_investment');
$profitRate1 = $block->getCurrentProduct()->getData('profit_rate');
$profitRate2 = $block->getCurrentProduct()->getData('profit_rate_2_years');
$profitRate3 = $block->getCurrentProduct()->getData('profit_rate_3_years');
$profitRate4 = $block->getCurrentProduct()->getData('profit_rate_4_years');
$profitRate5 = $block->getCurrentProduct()->getData('profit_rate_5_years');
if ($attributeData == 1) {
?>
<div class="container" style="background-color:#f4f4f4;">
    <div style="float:left; width:45%; padding-right:50px; margin-bottom:50px;">
        <h2><b>Investment Calculator</b></h2>
        <p>Investment calculator to evaluate various investment situations and find out corresponding schedules while considering starting and ending balance</p>
        <div class="field">
        <label class="label" for="investment_calc"><h3>Investment Amount</h3></label>
        <div class="control">
        <input name="investment_calc" id="investment_calc" title="Investment Amount" class="input-text" type="text" value="<?php echo ($productPrice); ?>" data-validate="{required:true}" readonly>
        </div>
        </div>
        <h3>Investment Term (Months):</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
        <input id="1" type="radio" class="months" value="<?php echo $profitRate1 ?>" name="rdmonths"/><span>12</span>
        <input id="2" type="radio" class="months" value="<?php echo $profitRate2 ?>" name="rdmonths"/><span>24</span>
        <input id="3" type="radio" class="months" value="<?php echo $profitRate3 ?>" name="rdmonths"/><span>36</span>
        <input id="4" type="radio" class="months" value="<?php echo $profitRate4 ?>" name="rdmonths"/><span>48</span>
        <input id="5" type="radio" class="months" value="<?php echo $profitRate5 ?>" checked="checked" name="rdmonths"/><span>60</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right; width:45%; margin-bottom:50px;">
        <h2><b>Representative</b></h2>
        <p>Total Amount:<span id="total-amount" style="margin-left:30px;"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "*": {
                    "myscript": {
                        "principal": "<?php echo $productPrice; ?>"
                    }
                }
        }
</script>
```

This is js code

```
  define([
    "jquery",
    "domReady"
], function($){
    "use strict";
        const myscript=function(){
            const profit = document.querySelector('input[name="rdmonths"]:checked').value;
            const id = document.querySelector('input[name="rdmonths"]:checked').id;
            const principal = document.querySelector('input[name="investment_calc"]').value;
            const time = id;
            const rate = profit/100;
            const n = 1;
        
            const compoundInterest = (p, t, r, n) => {
               const amount = p * (Math.pow((1 + (r / n)), t));
               return amount;
            };
        
            document.getElementById("total-amount").innerHTML = (compoundInterest(principal, time, rate, n).toFixed(2));   
            console.log(compoundInterest(principal, time, rate, n).toFixed(2));
        } 
            document.addEventListener('domReady',()=>{
                document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"][name="rdmonths"]').forEach(input=>{
                    input.addEventListener('click', myscript )
                })
            })
    return myscript;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change my js file

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "domReady!"
], function($){
    "use strict";
    return function myscript()
    {
        const profit = document.querySelector('input[name="rdmonths"]:checked').value;
            const id = document.querySelector('input[name="rdmonths"]:checked').id;
            const principal = document.querySelector('input[name="investment_calc"]').value;
            const time = id;
            const rate = profit/100;
            const n = 1;
        
            const compoundInterest = (p, t, r, n) => {
               const amount = p * (Math.pow((1 + (r / n)), t));
               return amount;
            };
            document.getElementById("total-amount").innerHTML = (compoundInterest(principal, time, rate, n).toFixed(2));               
        jQuery(".months").click(function(){
            const profit = document.querySelector('input[name="rdmonths"]:checked').value;
            const id = document.querySelector('input[name="rdmonths"]:checked').id;
            const principal = document.querySelector('input[name="investment_calc"]').value;
            const time = id;
            const rate = profit/100;
            const n = 1;
        
            const compoundInterest = (p, t, r, n) => {
               const amount = p * (Math.pow((1 + (r / n)), t));
               return amount;
            };
            document.getElementById("total-amount").innerHTML = (compoundInterest(principal, time, rate, n).toFixed(2));
          });
    }
});
```